# Vue - calling REST API from js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have an Axios API call that works perfectly on a Vue page. I need to make it a stand-alone callable module to be re-used multiple times in the app. Every attempt has failed and I am not sure if it's lack of experience with a stand-alone js or something else.

Here is the working vue code.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-if="posts && posts.length">
      <li v-for="post of posts">
        <p><strong>{{post.resID}}</strong></p>
        <p>{{post.Name}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
      <li v-for="error of errors">
        {{error.message}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "GetMxList",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },

  // Fetches posts when the component is created.
  created() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/...")
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Vue 3. Thank you for the answer. Sorry I was not clear. My goal is to create a module (like the rest.js) and then consume it in Pinia. The intent is to load once and then use the results often. Currently it works with a "static" load like the following code where the getJSONList calls a js module that returns a JSON formatted answer and puts that answer in MyList for use throughout the app. So the components just use Pinia mapping.

```
actions: {

    async fetchList() {
      
      const data = await getJSONList();
      this.Mylist = data;
    },
```

Many iterations. While this doesn't return aything it at least does not throw any errors...

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getJSONList() {
    
    const rest = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/rest/", // better still, use env vars
      });

    const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      return (await rest.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/")).data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.toJSON());  
      throw new Error(err.message);
    }
  };
    return (getPosts);
}
```

Comment: _"Every attempt has failed"_... please include these failed attempts in your question. There's really not much point only sharing code that works

Comment: Is this Vue version 2 or 3? Did you create your app with Vue CLI or [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue)

Comment: @Bill Stack Overflow is not a forum, so abandon ideas that treat it like a forum; this isn't a thread, it's a question, and details relevant to answering that question need to go in the question body, not in the answer field, so [edit] the question instead.

Comment: Thanks. First question and I didn't read all about it. Should I do that now, or just remember for the next round?

Comment: So what exactly failed with your `getJSONList()` implementation?

Comment: When it's connected to a js function that loads a static content, it gets the list. When I switch the function to do the Axios call it returns nothing - and I don't see any errors.

Comment: What exactly did your implementation of `getJSONList()` look like? Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant code

Comment: Your `getJSONList()` function returns a function, which you don't execute.

Comment: OK. Since I am a novice I thought the getPosts was a constant to be returned. How do I return the JSON from the Axios get?

Comment: @Bill getPosts is a function reference.  Just execute it; either in the return statement, or more likely where you execute the encapsulating function: `const fn = getJSONList(); const data = await fn(); ...`

Comment: @Bill For future reference, `() => {}` or `() => somethingToReturn` is what's called an arrow function; in this case it binds the function to the containing scope.  See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Using @Phil's code as a baseline I managed to get the function to hit the REST server. Server access still works when going straight to the page. However, I get the following error when I try to use the code below:               Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/rest/tctresidents/v1/Residents/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.           Not sure what to do next.

Comment: @Bill you said your code worked before and nothing should have changed regarding CORS access. If you need CORS access, you need to configure that on your API server.

Comment: @Phil, I am the one who configures it and I have it set to "Allow all" because I first saw it on the original access. That's why this is so confusing. Could the XML part of that be an issue? (Oh, and it works with Postman.) Grabbing at straws here.

Comment: Found it, problem solved (question answered). Using newly discovered skills in the developer tools (inspect) I found the call was appending /post to the base URL (duh BASE didn't register at first). Replaced Post with the actual path and it worked. Difference in the two was that @Phil used a baseURL and the other one did not. Thanks all!!!!!!!!

Comment: The difference being that perhaps you should have provided some better URLs in your question... `http://localhost:8080/rest/...` doesn't give us much to work with

Comment: @Phil, thanks. My first excursion into stack overflow and my first excursion into Axios consuming a REST resource (and not a lot of js either, obviously). The resource was private so I cut off the end. I should have changed the name. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you just need to move the Axios parts into a module and leave the consumption of the data to your components.

```js
// services/rest.js
import axios from "axios";

const rest = axios.create({
  // better still, use env vars to define your URLs
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/rest/tctresidents/v1",
});

// This is a function
export const getResidents = async () => {
  try {
    // the request path will be appended to the baseURL
    return (await rest.get("/Residents")).data;
  } catch (err) {
    // see https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors
    console.error(err.toJSON());

    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Then in your components / store / literally anywhere...

```js
import { getResidents } from "./path/to/services/rest";

export default {
  data: () => ({ residents: [], errors: [] }),
  async created() {
    try {
      this.residents = await getResidents();
    } catch (err) {
      this.errors.push(err);
    }
  },
};
```